# C# - Difficulty in Trying to Find the Error(s) in my String Bubble-Sort Algorithm

Tags: c#, string, bubble-sort

I have recently been trying to write an algorithm that would accept any number of strings from the user, merge them into one string and then sort them in ascending alphabetical order utilising the concept of Bubble-Sort. But I have been having trouble recently trying to determine wherein my errors lie, as while my code compiles and runs without any errors popping up the end result is strange. It simply shows the first string that was typed in unsorted with the rest of the strings coming out as blanks. I would be much obliged if anyone could assist me in solving this issue.

```
{
           int number_of_strings = 0;
           string[] array_of_strings;
           char[] array_of_char;
           char[] temporary_array;
           char[] temporary_character = new char[1];
           string[] suffix = new string[1];
           int length = 0;
           int counter = 0;
           int position = 0;
           int swap = 0;
           string[] temporary_hold = new string[1];

           Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of strings you would like to enter: ");
           Console.Write("> ");
           number_of_strings = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

           array_of_strings = new string[number_of_strings];

           for(counter = 0; counter < number_of_strings; counter++)
           {
               suffix = AddSuffix((counter + 1));

               Console.WriteLine("Please enter the {0}{1} string:", (counter + 1), suffix[0]);
               Console.Write("> ");
               temporary_hold[0] = Console.ReadLine();

               array_of_strings[counter] = temporary_hold[0];

               length = length + array_of_strings[counter].Length; 
           }

           array_of_char = new char[length]; 

           for(counter = 0; counter < number_of_strings; counter++)
           {
               temporary_array = array_of_strings[counter].ToCharArray();

               for( ;position < temporary_array.Length; position++)
               {
                   array_of_char[position] = temporary_array[position]; 
               }

               position = position + temporary_array.Length;
           }

           counter = 0;

           do
           {
               if(array_of_char[counter] > array_of_char[counter + 1])
               {
                   swap = 1;
                   temporary_character[0] = array_of_char[counter + 1];
                   array_of_char[counter + 1] = array_of_char[counter];
                   array_of_char[counter] = temporary_character[0];
               }
               else
               {
                   swap = 0;
               }   

                counter++;
           } while(swap != 0);

           Console.WriteLine("The resultant string is as follows:");

           for(counter = 0; counter < array_of_char.Length; counter++)
           {
               Console.Write("{0} ", array_of_char[counter]);
           };

           Console.ReadKey();
       }
   }

   static string[] AddSuffix(int number)
       {
           int greatness = 0;

           if(number > 10)
           {
               greatness = 1;
           };

           string input = string.Empty;
           string[] suffix = new string[1];
           input = number.ToString();

            if(input[0] == '1')
            {
                suffix[0] = "st";
            }
            else if(input[0] == '2')
            {
                suffix[0] = "nd";
            }
            else if(input[0] == '3')
            {
                suffix[0] = "rd";
            }
            else
            {
                suffix[0] = "st";
            }   

            if(greatness == 1)
            {
                if(input[1] == '1')
                {
                    suffix[0] = "st";
                }
                else if(input[1] == '2')
                {
                    suffix[0] = "nd";
                }
                else if(input[1] == '3')
                {
                    suffix[0] = "rd";
                }
                else
                {
                    suffix[0] = "st";
                }   
            };

                return suffix;
       }
```

I am using standard libraries, and the signature for the Main method is: static void Main(string[] args)

Comment: You can't merge the string and then expect to sort them.  The merge string is ONE object and you can sort one item.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. My main aim was to write all strings that the user entered into one string, and then to sort all elements of that string which contains all elements from the previous strings.

Comment: Then you need to parse or split the combined string into an array.

Answer (score -1):

I think something like this would work for you, (using linq)

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of strings you would like to enter: ");
    Console.Write("> ");
    var number_of_strings = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    var strings = new string[number_of_strings];
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_strings; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Please enter the {AddOrdinal(i+1)} string");
        strings[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    var str = string.Join("", strings);
    var strSorted = string.Concat(str.OrderBy(x=>x));
    Console.WriteLine(strSorted);
}

public static string AddOrdinal(int num)
{
    if (num <= 0) return num.ToString();

    switch (num % 100)
    {
        case 11:
        case 12:
        case 13:
            return num + "th";
    }

    switch (num % 10)
    {
        case 1:
            return num + "st";
        case 2:
            return num + "nd";
        case 3:
            return num + "rd";
        default:
            return num + "th";
    }

}
```